# VS2008: "Error whilst trying to run project:Unable to start program. The debugger's protocol is incompatibile with the debugee"

Tags: c#, .net

I think i know roughly why i'm getting this message. I opened a VS2008 project in VS2010, realised my code wont work with .NET 4, so i re opened it in VS2008 but now it wont build.

Can someone advise me how i can get this back to executing? I deleted the debug folder and built again but nothing has changed. I also cleaned the project and solution.

Please help

Comment: Won't build, or won't debug? The error in your title suggests it's an execution time error, not a build error.

Comment: And by the way, your code *should* build with VS 2010 if you keep the project's setting to target the .NET 3.5 Framework. You can specify that under * Project -> Properties... *.

Comment: No its because im using a user-written wrapper which doesn't like .NET 4.0 for some reason, hence i had to go back to .NET3.5.

Has anyone got any ideas how i can get this working again?

Comment: It will build, it wont execute